# Equivalent for Java System.arraycopy in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I convert the below java code to equivalent dart.

`private static final byte[] mIdBytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x7E};`

`byte[] data;`

`System.arraycopy(mIdBytes, 2, data, 0, 4);`

Is there any Dart method that does a similar kind of operation?

I was looking into this:
https://pub.dev/documentation/ckb_dart_sdk/latest/ckb-utils_number/arrayCopy.html

Comment: Can you show me, what does `data` and `macIdBytes` consists? Also, what is the expected output you want

Comment: @Alok Updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the way to do it.
you can just use

`List.copyRange(data, 0, mIdBytes, 2);`

Answer (score 7):

To match Java's `System.arrayCopy(source, sourceOffset, target, targetOffset, length)`
you should use

```dart
 target.setRange(targetOffset, targetOffset + length, source, sourceOffset);
```

This is more efficient than using `List.copyRange` for some lists, for example copying between typed-data lists with the same element size (like two `Uint8List`s).

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround I kinda found to be done in your case. This is called [sublist()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/sublist.html), this method will take the `start index`, and an `end index`.

**IDEA:**

> 1. Use `sublist()`, and copy the elements to be started from, that sourcePos = you_pos
> 2. Source array will be used like `sourceArray.sublist(startIndext, endIndex)`
> 3. The destination array will be initialized with the value using sublist()
> 4. Till what length the item should be added would be mentioned in the `end index+2`, since it will ignore the last item, and copy till the index-1

**FINAL CODE**

```
void main() {
  List<int> source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  List<int> target = [];
  int startPos = 1;
  int length = 4;
  
  // to ensure the length doesn't exceeds limit
  // length+2 because, it targets on the end index, that is 4 in source list
  // but the end result should be length+2 to contain a length of 5 items
  if(length+1 <= source.length-1){
    target = source.sublist(startPos, length+2);
    print(target);
  }else{
    print('Cannot copy items till $length: index out of bound');
  }
}

//OUTPUT
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Even this looks pretty, but List.copyRange is straightforward to use.

Comment: I know @Uday, just wanted to let you know about this. Or it might help the community in future :) I upvoted your answer too, since I liked it.